# Tournure « est-ce que » utilisée deux fois dans une phrase avec la conjonction « ou »

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions, interrogative

J'ai reçu un e-mail qui contenait la phrase suivante:

> Dans la section 1.4, est-ce qu'il faut résoudre l'exercice depuis le
>   début ou est-ce que l'on peut utiliser les réponses de la section 1.3 ?

Pensez-vous que c'est correct d'utiliser « est-ce que » deux fois comme cela ?

Dans ce genre de situation, doit-on écrire

- Est-ce que [ première question ] ou [ deuxième question ] ?

ou bien

- Est-ce que [ première question ] ou est-ce que [ deuxième question ]
  ?

Comment: Je pense que c'est toujours correct, en tout cas je ne vois pas pourquoi ce serait faux, même d'en utiliser cinq dans la même phrase, après c'est surtout une question de style. Dans cet exemple, ça passe d'autant mieux que le double *est-ce que* accentue l'opposition entre la première proposition où *il faut* et la seconde où *on peut*. C'est mon ressenti sans avoir vérifié dans aucune source.

Comment: Out of curiosity : Pour recevoir de genre de mail, vous êtes manifestement prof ou équivalent. Prof... de quoi ?... je veux dire : t'es prof de lettres ou t'es prof de maths ? Et si, par hasard ou inadvertance t'es prof de lettres... ces lettres est-ce qu'elles sont classiques ou est-ce qu'elles sont modernes ?

Comment: De toutes les manières cette question est rigoureusement **stupide**. On parle manifestement de l'exercice 1. Il y avait non moins manifestement 1.1 (fait) 1.2 (fait) 1.3 (fait). Alors comme ça vous avez des élèves qui se demandent si, rien que pour 1.4, il faut recommencer au début et recopier 1.1, 1.2 et 1.3 ? Au secours! Jycroipa! Fayot oui!

Comment: Je ne suis pas professeur, mais je fais des séances de travaux dirigés pour le cours d'informatique. Je n'ai pas copié l'e-mail entier ici, car ce n'était pas pertinent. Et on ne parle pas « manifestement de l'exercice 1 », comme vous avez imaginé, mais des sections 1.3 et 1.4 d'une liste d'exercices où les étudiants devraient rendre un fichier Python pour chaque section et cet étudiant a trouvé que les fonctions faites dans la section 1.3 étaient utiles pour la section 1.4. S'il vous plaît, soyez plus poli dans les prochains commentaires.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oui, la phrase est correcte et idiomatique.

L'absence du deuxième ***est-ce que*** la placerait dans un registre plus relâché :

> Dans la section 1.4, **est-ce qu**'il faut résoudre l'exercice depuis le début ou **on peut** utiliser les réponses de la section 1.3 ?

la formule *est-ce que* est le marqueur de la question, il en fait partie. Il faudrait donc plutôt analyser la phrase comme :

- [ première question ] ou [ deuxième question ].

Une manière plus soutenue d'écrire cette phrase pourrait être :

> Dans la section 1.4, **faut-il** résoudre l'exercice depuis le début ou **peut-on** utiliser les réponses de la section 1.3 ?

On peut aussi avoir une approche hybride avec :

> Dans la section 1.4, **est-ce qu**'il faut résoudre l'exercice depuis le début ou **peut-on** utiliser les réponses de la section 1.3 ?

Comment: Dans ce cas, le *ou peut-on* ne le placerait pas forcément dans le registre soutenu, étant donné que *ou on peut* n'est pas très facile à prononcer rapidement.

Comment: @Lyzvaleska L'inversion verbe sujet est toujours plus soutenue que *est-ce que*. La facilité de prononciation n'intervient pas vraiment ici, d'autant plus que *ou on peut* ne me semble pas spécialement difficile à prononcer. La phrase la plus courante en français parlé supprimerait aussi le premier *est-ce que* pour donner: ***Dans la section 1.4, il faut résoudre l'exercice depuis le début ou on peut utiliser les réponses de la section 1.3 ?***

Answer (score 1):

Répéter « est-ce que » une fois ne donne pas une impression de lourdeur; on peut donc le répéter. On peut aussi se passer de la répétition (en changeant légèrement la syntaxe).

- Dans la section 1.4, est-ce qu'il faut résoudre l'exercice depuis le début ou  peut-on utiliser les réponses de la section 1.3 ?

Pour plus d'une répétition, en particulier dans des questions courtes une certaine monotonie se fait sentir et, à mon avis il vaut mieux éviter trois occurrences consécutives de « est-ce que », sauf dans un but stylistique, le but particulier dans ce cas-ci étant d'insister sur l'aspect incroyable de la possibilité de ce qui est demandé ([réf.](http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/atelier/figures3.html)).

- Est-ce que l'on peut crier et est-ce que l'on peut chanter et est-ce que l'on peut parler toute la nuit ? Oh ! Mais c'est l'endroit rêvé ! (*grammaticalement correct*)
- (*Sans effet de style*)   Est-ce que l'on peut crier, chanter, parler toute la nuit ?
- (*Autre tournure pour le même effet de style*)   Est-ce que l'on peut crier, et chanter, et parler toute la nuit ?

En ce qui concerne les questions longues, il me semble que la répétition est préférable mais pas souvent une nécessité.

- Est-ce que les enfants, lorsqu'il sont assez âgés mais pas encore majeures, ont la liberté de prendre beaucoup d'initiatives personnelles, en particulier en ce qui concerne leur futur emploi, ou est-ce que, au contraire, ils seraient contraints à une conduite strictement dictée par le système ?